# MapBox in Android : Unable to request location permissions in a fragment using requestLocationPermissions method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mapbox

For my coding school project I am using mapbox map in a fragment. I manage to add map to a fragment with finding my (the user) location. However, it finds my location only when I go manually to my phone settings and allow the location permissions for the app. I was following mapbox tutorials and documentation, however it seems most of it is being written for MapBox map to be used in the activity. In the mapbox tutorials I see that the following is being used:

```
private void enableLocation() {
    if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(getContext())) {
        initializeLocationEngine();
        initializeLocationLayer();
    } else {
        permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this); // THIS, HOWEVER WORKS IN THE FRAGMENT
       permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this); //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
    }
}
```

The code that I have shown above in my app I use in fragments onCreateView, and since the parameter for the requestLocationPermissions method is the activity, I am unable to make that method run. I tried different options to refer to mainActivity that the fragment is associated to, however with no success. Therefore, my question is - is there some simple quick go around this problem where I can pass somehow activity in this method?

Comment: [This example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/show-a-users-location-on-a-fragment/) in our documentation shows the recommended approach for showing a user's location in a map fragment on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do `requestPermissions(permissionsList, REQUEST_CODE);` to request permission from within the fragment. 
 There is no need to pass the `mainActivity` context.

How do you enable your location? I generally like to do it this way:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

    mapboxMap.setStyle(new Style.Builder()
            .fromUri("mapbox://styles/mapbox/navigation-guidance-night-v4")
            .withSource(new GeoJsonSource(ISOCHRONE_RESPONSE_GEOJSON_SOURCE_ID)), style -> {

        mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setCompassMargins(0, 180, 20, 0);
        // Map is set up and the style has loaded. Now you can add
        // data or make other map adjustments
        MainActivity.this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;

        trafficPlugin = new TrafficPlugin(mapView, mapboxMap, Objects.requireNonNull(
                mapboxMap.getStyle()));
        this.trafficPlugin.setVisibility(false);

        this.style = style;

        // Create an empty GeoJSON source using the empty feature collection
        setUpSource();

        mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        mapboxMap.addOnMapLongClickListener(MainActivity.this);

        initEmptyLayer(Objects.requireNonNull(mapboxMap.getStyle()));
        setUpImage(Objects.requireNonNull(mapboxMap.getStyle()));

        enableLocationComponent(style);
    });
}
```

Then on my enableLocationCompnent function:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})
private void enableLocationComponent(Style style) {
    // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
    if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {

        LocationComponentOptions locationComponentOptions = LocationComponentOptions.builder(this)
                .layerAbove("empty-layer")
                .build();

        LocationComponentActivationOptions locationComponentActivationOptions = LocationComponentActivationOptions
                .builder(this, style)
                .locationComponentOptions(locationComponentOptions)
                .build();

        locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
        // Activate with options
        locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(locationComponentActivationOptions);

        // Enable to make component visible
        locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

        // Set the component's camera mode
        locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
        locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);
        initLocationEngine();

    } else {
        permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
        permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I enable my location using this:     public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        map = mapboxMap;
        enableLocation();


        locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationEngine.setInterval(50000); // 
        locationEngine.activate();
        Location lastLocation = locationEngine.getLastLocation();}